# Sitecore Scheduled Task not working on a CD server

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I am accessing Sitecore from staging and configured a schedule task.
Staging has the following databases configured:

```
master, web --> for staging
live --> db for cd1/cd2 server.
```

The scheduled task is working on staging but not on cd1.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7):

This is a normal behaviour in Sitecore, you need to add agents for schedule task on CD.

You need to add in your config files :

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<!-- adjust the value according related infrastructure -->
<sitecore>
     <scheduling>
        <agent name="Web_Database_Agent" type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent" method="Run" interval="24:00:00">
            <param desc="database">web</param>
            <param desc="schedule root">/sitecore/system/tasks/schedules</param>
            <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
        </agent>
    </scheduling>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. we have a configuration switchMasterToWeb.config  would that take care for switching to web ?

Comment: yes but you need to have this configuration to run scheduling tasks

Comment: note: from what I've seen an interval value of 24:00:00 is invalid and should rather be 23:59:59